# Agree "to share" or "to sharing"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, expressions, verbs

After registering on an irish website, the following message showed up below the login form:

> By pressing login I agree ***to sharing*** my personal details and contact information with this government body.

Although I'm not a native english speaker, I admit that the above expression bothered me.

Doesn't someone agree ***to do something***? Therefore, ***agree to share*** his/her information? Why is the -ing form being used?

Comment: Sounds funny that way. It's not just you.

Comment: @tchrist What's funny?

Comment: BBC: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv267.shtml  See also: http://www.linguarama.com/ps/technology-themed-english/common-problems.htm

Comment: To me, _I agree to share_ (in this context) sounds like a one-time thing.  You type in your name and phone number and they get it.  _I agree to sharing_, on the other hand, sounds like an ongoing relationship.  They'll get your info not only now, but whenever you use the site going forward.  But I have no real justification for this and I'm not Irish.

Comment: It's easy: No one is asking you to share anything.  The site will take care of all that. You are not even doing the sharing, they are and will be sharing whenever they like. You are agreeing to let the site share your data (with others who pay) now and in the future, a whole lot of sharing.

Comment: @YosefBaskin  Guess that's entirely true. However, we need to find a source that defines or explains this interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Here “to” is not the infinitive marker, but a preposition. Prepositions are always followed by a noun or noun phrase. You can tell “to” is the infinitive marker if the subject preceding it (you) performs the action after it (share).